# How to simulate back tab in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simulate tabbing in a textarea, so far tab forward works but I'm not quite sure how to make backtab work. Any suggestions on how to do this, or better ways to do it would be helpful.

```
$('textarea').on('keydown mousedown', function(e){
  var val = this.value,
      start = this.selectionStart,
      end = this.selectionEnd;
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    console.log('shift')
    if (e.which == 9 || e.keyCode == 9) {
      console.log('shift + tab')
      e.preventDefault();
      this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);
    }
  } else if (e.which == 9 || e.keyCode == 9) {
    console.log('tab')
    e.preventDefault();
    this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);
  }
})
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you'll want to edit the text area to remove the '\t' character if there is one at the start of the line? What browsers are you targeting? pre IE8 you'll probably have to mess with text ranges, otherwise you could use selectionStart/selectionEnd to find the line you are on and remove the first instance of \t on that line.

Comment: Is this really important?  I ask this because you are overriding the expected behavior of a browser, something I do not do light lightly.

Comment: As a side project I'm building a code editor, this will only override the textarea's that are being used in each code panel. The code above is just an example. The final code won't target every textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might get you started.

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown mousedown', function(e) {
  var val   = this.value,
      start = this.selectionStart,
      end   = this.selectionEnd;

  if (e.which == 9 || e.keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (e.shiftKey) {
      var firstTabPoint = val.lastIndexOf('\n', start) + 1;

      if (val.substring(firstTabPoint, firstTabPoint + 1) == '\t') {
        var startString = val.substr(0, firstTabPoint);
        var endString = val.substr(firstTabPoint + 1);

        this.value = startString + endString;
        this.setSelectionRange(start - 1, end - 1);
      }
    } else {
      this.value = val.substring(0, start) + '\t' + val.substring(end);
      this.setSelectionRange(start + 1, end + 1);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="20" cols="100">
Add some lines in here, tab them, and then try untabbing.
</textarea>
```

As a side note, you might look into the attribute `contenteditable="true"` if you are making a text editor application.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer! Before starting this project I hadn't heard of a contenteditable attr, I'll look into it. Is there an advantage/disadvantage to using one or the other?

Comment: A contenteditable element will allow edits to any text within it, but still allow tags within. So you would be able to implement syntax highlighting and other features that are useful to a code editor that aren't possible with a textarea.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for for the information. Looking into it now.